# CMD Long beep (duration)

Tags: windows, windows-7, cmd, beep

How can i produce a long beep ONLY (no 3rd tools) with the cmd?
(only one cmd command)

I know ^G - but there isn´t any duration. Its only a short beep.

Comment: You might want to check http://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt

Comment: hm, maybe this was not clearly. I search for something like this "beep(2500(<-duration))".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop and repeat the echo ^G  (BELL Char)

Duration will depend on your hardware.

And you could alternate calls to the color command to have the window flash as well.

Also you can create a set of ascii file with just the number of bells you want and do a type on it.

Comment: Umm... It works for me on Win7. But it does rely on hardware pieces that may not be setup consistently everywhere.